# Using a function and .replace

Tags: python, function

I am trying to adapt this piece of code i have found so i can build a game. This is the original code i have found on the interment but when i run it i have two errors i can't solve.

The code is originally for Python2.5 and i'm using Python3.3 i have changed some obvious differences can anyone please help me?

Why isn't this working???

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text

my_text = ("Hello everybody.")

reps = {"H":"|-|", "e":"3", "o":"0"}

txt = replace_all(my_text, reps)
print (txt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3 dictionaries only have a `dict.items()` method, `dict.iteritems()` has been removed.

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.items():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text

my_text = "Hello everybody."

reps = {"H": "|-|", "e": "3", "o": "0"}

txt = replace_all(my_text, reps)
```

works just fine.

However, it would be much more efficient to use [`str.translate()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) here:

```
trans_map = {ord(k): v for k, v in reps.items()}
txt = my_text.translate(trans_map)
```

Demo:

```
>>> replace_all(my_text, reps)
'|-|3ll0 3v3ryb0dy.'
>>> trans_map = {ord(k): v for k, v in reps.items()}
>>> my_text.translate(trans_map)
'|-|3ll0 3v3ryb0dy.'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i in dic:
        text = text.replace(i, dic[i])
    return text
```